# Solve for deceleration in exponential decay equation

Tags: exponential-function

$$y = y_0 + v_0\cdot d\frac{1 - d^{t}}{1 - d}$$

$y$ = final position

$y0$ = initial position

$v0$ = initial velocity

$d$ = deceleration

$t$ = elapsed time

How do I solve for $d$?

Specifically, this step is where I'm stuck:

$$\frac{y - y_0}{v_0} = d\frac{1 - d^{t}}{1 - d}$$

Comment: What are $d,t,y_0,y,v_0$?

Comment: @GoodDeeds Updated the question!

Comment: I do not think that you can get an analytical solution for $d$. Numerical methods probably.